# React setting state to child component causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, setstate

I have a page with some dropdown menu's used to search some content, the dropdown is a non-functional component. The page is a listsing page. Not important but gives some context.

I do some calculation on the listing page and update the state, then I pass this state into the Dropdown component. However, I'm getting an infinite loop and I'm not sure how to stop it or where I'm going wrong.

my listing page is here:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    let industryList = this.createList(this.props.data.mainYaml.caseStudiesDropdowns[0].items)
    let areaList = this.createList(this.props.data.mainYaml.caseStudiesDropdowns[1].items)
    let techniqueList = this.createList(this.props.data.mainYaml.caseStudiesDropdowns[2].items)

    this.state = {
      industry: "All Industries",
      area: "All Areas",
      technique: [],
      industries: industryList,
      areas: areaList,
      techniques: techniqueList
    }
  }

  createList = (listItems) => {
    let listArr = []

    listItems.forEach((item) => {
      let obj = {
        name: item,
        disabled: false
      }

      listArr.push(obj)
    })

    return listArr
  }

  filterCaseStudies = (caseStudies) => {

    const filterIndustry = (caseStudies) => {
      if (this.state.industry == "All Industries") {
        return caseStudies
      } else {
        return caseStudies.filter((study) => study.node.industry == this.state.industry)
      }
    }

    const filterArea = (caseStudies) => {
      if (this.state.area == "All Areas") {
        return caseStudies
      } else {
        return caseStudies.filter((study) => study.node.area == this.state.area)
      }
    }

    const filterTechnique = (caseStudies) => {
      if (this.state.technique.length === 0) {
        return caseStudies
      } else {
        let matchedStudies = []

        caseStudies.forEach((study) => {
          let count = 0;
          let techCount = study.node.technique.length - 1;

          study.node.technique.forEach((item, i) => {
            this.state.technique.forEach((selectedItems) => {
              if (selectedItems == item) {
                count++;
                return
              }
            })

            if (i == techCount && count > 0) {
              study.node.count = count
              matchedStudies.push(study)
            }
          })
        })

        matchedStudies.sort((a, b) => b.node.count - a.node.count);
        return matchedStudies;
      }
    }

    let industryMatches = filterIndustry(caseStudies)
    let areaMatches = filterArea(industryMatches)

    this.filterDropdowns(areaMatches)

    let techniqueMatches = filterTechnique(areaMatches)

    return techniqueMatches;
  }

  filterDropdowns = (filteredCaseStudies) => {
    console.log(filteredCaseStudies)
    let disabledIndustries = [];
    let disabledAreas = [];
    let disabledTechniques = [];

    this.state.industries.forEach((industry) => {
      let obj = {
        name: industry.name
      }

      if (industry.name == "All Industries") {
        console.log(industry.name)
        obj.disabled = false;
        disabledIndustries.push(obj);
      } else {
        obj.disabled = true;

        filteredCaseStudies.forEach((study) => {
          if (study.node.industry == industry.name) {
            obj.disabled = false;
          }
        })

        disabledIndustries.push(obj);
      }
    })

    console.log(disabledIndustries)
    this.setState({industries: disabledIndustries})
  }

  getCaseStudies = (caseStudies) => {
    let filteredCaseStudies = this.filterCaseStudies(caseStudies)

    if (filteredCaseStudies.length > 0) {
      return filteredCaseStudies.map((study, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i} className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 px-4 mb-5">
            <CaseStudyListItem
              data={study.node}
              className="CaseStudyListItem--lg"
              index={i}/>
          </div>
        )
      })
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 px-4 mb-5">
          <h4>We're Sorry!</h4>
          <p>We can't seem to find any case studies that match your search. Please try other search terms.</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  dropdownChange = (selected, name) => {
    this.setState({[name]: selected})
  }

  render () {
    console.log(this.state)

    return (
      <Layout bodyClass="k-reverse-header">
        <div className="CaseStudies">
          <section className="CaseStudies__header k-bg--grey">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="d-flex k-row">
                <div className="col-12 px-4">
                  <DropdownSelect className="CaseStudies__search-industry mb-4" data={this.props.data.mainYaml.caseStudiesDropdowns[0]} list={this.state.industries} selected={this.dropdownChange} />
                  <DropdownSelect className="CaseStudies__search-area mb-4" data={this.props.data.mainYaml.caseStudiesDropdowns[1]} list={this.state.areas} selected={this.dropdownChange} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section className="CaseStudies__list">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="d-flex flex-wrap k-row">
                {this.getCaseStudies(this.props.data.allCaseStudiesYaml.edges)}
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

I believe the issue happens as I pass the state into the Dropdown component, it is also updated in the filterDropdowns function. The Dropdown component code is as follows.

```
  const DropdownSelect = ({ data, className, list, selected}) => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [activeItem, changeActiveItem] = useState(data.placeholder);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
      // If the menu is open and the clicked target is not within the menu,
      // then close the menu
      if (isActive && ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setActive(false)
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside)

    return () => {
      // Cleanup the event listener
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside)
    }
  }, [isActive])

  const toggleClass = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  }

  const buildDropdown  = () => {
    const splitArr = (arr, len) => {
      let chunks = [], i = 0, n = arr.length;
      while (i < n) {
        chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
      }
      return chunks;
    }

    const buildList = (items) => {
      return items.map((item, i) =>
        <li
          key={i}
          className={`DropdownSelect__list-item ${activeItem == item.name ? "active" : ""} ${item.disabled ? "disabled" : ""}`}
          onClick={() => itemClicked(item.name, selected, data.name)}
        >
          {item.name}
        </li>
      )
    }

    const itemClicked = (item, selected, search) => {
      changeActiveItem(item)
      selected(item, search)
    }

    const arrLen = list.length < 10 ? 3 : 4;
    const listsArr = splitArr(list, arrLen);

    return listsArr.map((list, i) =>
      <ul key={i} className="DropdownSelect__list">
        {buildList(list)}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={`DropdownSelect ${className ? className : ''}`} ref={ref}>
      <div
        className={`DropdownSelect__button ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}
        onClick={toggleClass}
      >
        {activeItem == null ? data.placeholder : activeItem}
      </div>
      <div className={`DropdownSelect__list-wrapper ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}>{buildDropdown}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DropdownSelect
```

I feel like i could have all of my state in the listing page but then the Dropdown component is pointless as it wouldn't be self sufficient and usable elsewhere.

I guess I want to know how I break this loop but also what are my bad practices here? ie am I using state wrongly?

Any help greatly appreciated!

PS Here's the React error i get

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right...

In your render, you have `{this.getCaseStudies(this.props.data.allCaseStudiesYaml.edges)}`. `getCaseStudies` calls `filterCaseStudies`, which calls `filterDropdowns`, which has a `setState` in it. When a `setState` occurs, the page re-renders, causing the page to go through all those function calls again, another `setState` occurs, the page re-renders again, forever, causing an infinite loop.

You'll have to re-write your code somewhat. You could possibly use that state to store the data in a different format, like an array, and map the data in your render?